# how to delete hyphen in filename and add something to the name ? python

Tags: python

i have a folder with a lot of files like that:

```
2012-05-09.txt
2012-05-10.txt
2012-05-11.txt
etc.
```

now i wanna delete the hyphen and add " _PHOTOS_LOG " that it looks in the end like this:

```
20120509_PHOTOS_LOG.txt
20120510_PHOTOS_LOG.txt
20120511_PHOTOS_LOG.txt
etc.
```

How to do ?

thats the code now:

```
//updated the code, now its working 

import os
import glob
import os.path
import sys


src = 'D:\\testing/hyphen1'

src = r'D:\testing\test'

for fn in os.listdir(src):
    new_filename = fn.replace('-','').replace('.txt', '_PHOTOS_LOG.txt')
    fn = os.path.join(src, fn)
    new_filename = os.path.join(src, new_filename)
    try:
        os.rename(fn, new_filename)
    except (WindowsError, OSError):
        print 'Error renaming "%s" to "%s"' % (fn, new_filename)
        print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Comment: Are there any other files in that folder? In other words, do all the filenames end in `.txt`?

Comment: yes in the whole folder are only .txt files

Comment: You may want to add the error message you are getting with the code you show.

Comment: Error renaming "2012-05-09.txt" to "20120509.txt"
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Good news .. it should have worked without the os .path.join etc if you had the script and files in the same directory since no paths would have been involved (I eluded to the os module and this in my answer). Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_filename = old_filename.replace("-", "").replace(".txt", "_PHOTOS_LOG.txt")
```

That will get you the new filename, if you want to rename all the files, then:

```
import os
for old_filename in os.listdir("."):
    new_filename = old_filename.replace("-", "").replace(".txt", "_PHOTOS_LOG.txt")
    os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Comment: yea i need to do it for all but the .txt should not be replaced. file have to look like " 20120509_PHOTOS_LOG.txt "

Comment: do u know other way to change the names ? get this error Error renaming "2012-05-09.txt" to "20120509.txt"
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1):

For all of your files in your *current* directory:

```
import os

for fn in os.listdir('.'):
   new_filename = fn.replace('-','').replace('.txt', '_PHOTOS_LOG.txt')
   os.rename(fn, new_filename)
```

Using [os.rename()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.rename#os.rename) to change the filenames.

The individual file names will end up a series of strings, so while you usually would want to use methods from the [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module, you can simply treat these as strings *since you are not looking at paths, but simple filenames* and use [replace()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) to create the new names.

--

Example for one filename to show transformation:

```
fn ='2012-05-09.txt'
```

then

```
fn.replace('-','').replace('.txt', '_PHOTOS_LOG.txt')
```

will yield `'20120509_PHOTOS_LOG.txt'`

Comment: @zeromancer  `"2011-02-14.txt" to "20110214.txt"` makes no sense, the new name constructed by my script (see my *single string* example) does not build a string like that.

Comment: I changed it, no effect. is there other way to change the name of the file ?!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the rename something like this:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        newFilename = filename.replace("-", "")
        os.rename(filename, newFilename[:7]+"_PHOTO_LOG.txt")
```

os.listdir(".") returns the names of the entries in the current folder
filename.endswith(".txt") verifies if the filename is one of your text files
if it is, it removes the - and adds the _PHOTO_LOG at the end

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified that happen

Comment: i didn't get that error, but it seems that giving the absolute path to listdir should work. Try writing it like this: os.listdir("c:\\myDir"), or whatever your folder is

Comment: are you trying to do the rename under windows or linux?

Comment: under windows. Error renaming "2011-02-14.txt" to "20110214.txt"
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the list of files
and rename them according to your needs:

```
import os
import glob
for name in glob.glob('*.txt'):
  newname = "%s_PHOTOS_LOG.txt" % name.replace('-','')[:-4]
  os.rename(name, newname)
```

The `glob.glob` function produces a list of `.txt` files in the current directory.

Comment: I perfectly understand that. glob.glob produces a list, not the files.